# What is the meaning of "had+...." here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My grandfather's desk **had the best light in the room.**

I think the bolded phrase means— desk possessed the best light in that room. (Am I correct?)

Comment: **How are we supposed to know without more context?** My **guess** would be that the desk was near a window from which it received natural light.

Comment: But yes, "possessed" is almost certainly the correct interpretation.

Comment: Desks don't possess light. Light falls on or hits or illuminates some thing.

Comment: I think you meant `my grandfather's desk`.

Comment: It could have a really nice Tiffany lampshade. Or it could be in the sun. Or I guess something else in specialised circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have) has this definition of "have" that applies:

> **3 :** to stand in a certain relationship to
> *we will have the wind at our backs*

In that example sentence, the people speaking certainly don't *possess* the wind at their backs, but have a certain relationship to it in the same way the desk has a certain relationship to the light.

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable, but I think my sentence may be interpreted differently without context.

Comment: @Sam How do you think it might be interpreted?

Comment: @gotube - At least in the UK, an electric lamp can be semi-informally called a 'light'. My grandfather's desk had the best light in the room, with a 100-watt bulb, a polished brass stem, and a glossy green shade.

Answer (score 1):

"My grandfather's desk had the best light in the room."

Translates as:  The best PLACE for light (say for reading) would be at "my grandfather's desk".

Implies the question:  "where is the best light" which may or may not have been explicitly stated.  For example, "I need a place to write" implies a physical need for light (writing in the dark is usually not a good plan).  "Has" is used in the same was as "Joe's Pub has the best beer".

In this meaning, "my grandfather's desk" possesses "the best light" whether it is sunshine, an electric light or some other form of light. And, if it is light -- or beer -- that I want, then "my grandfather's desk" or "Joe's Pub" are the places to find what I want.